# CMake: set compile options and compile features per project

Tags: cmake

I have a code base (say, a repository) containing several software components (executables, libraries). All is built using CMake with individual targets for each component.

Now, I know that the modern way to set compiler flags is target-specific:

```
target_compile_options(foo PRIVATE -Werror -Wall -Wextra -pedantic)
target_compile_features(foo PRIVATE cxx_std_17)
```

However, I want to have the same flags for all targets in the entire project. Writing these lines for each single target leads to code duplication and is error-prone (especially when the number of flags increases). Is there some way to attach compiler flags to projects rather than targets?

I know that I can add options to the top-level directory like that:

```
add_compile_options(-Werror -Wall -Wextra -pedantic)
```

But I'm not sure if that's the way to go, and also I'm not sure how to do the same for the compile features (`cxx_std_17`).

Comment: You shouldn't set warning flags in the project itself. For one, they are compiler specific. Supporting warning flags for multiple compilers quickly turns into a mess of conditionals, in particular if you support multiple versions of the same compiler that have different warnings that you need to disable. Instead you can either use toolchain files or compiler+compiler-version specific additional cmake scripts that you inject into your builds with -DCMAKE_PROJECT_INCLUDE / -DCMAKE_PROJECT_INCLUDE_BEFORE.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Now, I know that the modern way to set compiler flags is target-specific:
>
> ```
> target_compile_options(foo PRIVATE -Werror -Wall -Wextra -pedantic)
> target_compile_features(foo PRIVATE cxx_std_17)
> ```

This is actually not the best/most modern way. If you're using CMake 3.19+, the best thing to do is to create a [*preset*](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-presets.7.html).

Create a file called `CMakePresets.json` next to your top-level `CMakeLists.txt` with the following content:

```
{
  "version": 1,
  "cmakeMinimumRequired": {
    "major": 3,
    "minor": 19,
    "patch": 0
  },
  "configurePresets": [
    {
      "name": "default",
      "displayName": "Default",
      "description": "Default build using Ninja",
      "generator": "Ninja",
      "binaryDir": "${sourceDir}/build",
      "cacheVariables": {
        "CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS": "-Werror -Wall -Wextra -pedantic",
        "CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD": "17",
        "CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED": "YES",
        "CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS": "OFF"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Then configure with:

```
$ cmake --preset=default
```

---

The *reason* for doing things this way is because (ideally) **nothing should be in the CMakeLists.txt that isn't *absolutely* required to build your project**. Warning flags are not in this set, so they belong here. Otherwise, you inflict potentially invalid flags on your end-users. This is surprisingly common with warning flags. There are some flags that are GCC or Clang only, others that have been removed or renamed, and others whose sensitivity has changed across releases. If your user manually adds `-Werror` via `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` and you add a flag some other way, problems are likely.

This does mean that for *libraries*, it is very often appropriate to set `cxx_std_NN` via `target_compile_features`, where `NN` is the *minimum* compatible C++ version (not the *preferred* version, though they might coincide) of the library. This is because the feature can be set in the `INTERFACE` (equiv. `PUBLIC`) property to make sure that linkees are using a new enough version for the library's headers. If both `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD` and the compile feature are set, the maximum will be used.

In older versions of CMake, a [toolchain file](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html) could be used for this same purpose.

Comment: That sounds great! Never heard of this feature before! Give me a bit of time to try it out, before I accept the answer.

Comment: @GeorgP. Sure, take your time

Comment: I ran into a similar problem, but setting `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` will override all defaults by CMake. On windows for example, it is "/DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3 /GR /EHsc". You can either specify all those options again - or you can set the environment variable `CXXFLAGS` (using presets). The value is prepended to the default values.