# Can you set compiler options/definitions for all dependencies [cmake]?

Tags: c++, cmake

I have several projects in the same repository which all have the same dependencies, and each of these in turn depend on more libraries (simplified structure shown below).

[image: Project structure]

Now, these projects are all built with different compile options/definitions, and their dependencies also need to be built with those flags.

What is the best way to do this? Currently I'm using

```
add_library(P1_configuration INTERFACE)
add_library(P2_configuration INTERFACE)
target_compile_options(P1_configuration INTERFACE ${P1_compile_options})
target_compile_definitions(P1_configuration INTERFACE ${P1_compile_definitions})
target_compile_options(P2_configuration INTERFACE ${P2_compile_options})
target_compile_definitions(P2_configuration INTERFACE ${P2_compile_definitions})
```

in the toplevel CMakeList file, and

```
target_link_libraries(P1 P1_configuration)
target_link_libraries(A PRIVATE P1_configuration)
target_link_libraries(B PRIVATE P1_configuration)
target_link_libraries(C PRIVATE P1_configuration)
target_link_libraries(D PRIVATE P1_configuration)

target_link_libraries(P2 P2_configuration)
target_link_libraries(A PRIVATE P2_configuration)
...
```

in each of the project's CMakeList files.

Will this work?
Is there a better way? There are a lot more dependencies in reality and it'd be quite easy to miss one

I found this [similar question](https://%20%5Bhttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/67385282/cmake-set-compile-options-and-compile-features-per-project%5D%5B2%5D), but this seems to be about setting options for the entire repository instead of individual projects within a repository.

Comment: Why not just `target_compile_options(P1 PUBLIC ${P1_compile_options})` and then they will be propagated every time you do `target_link_libraries(P1 PUBLIC whatever)` (or PRIVATE, if let's say C does not depend on A, but from the diagram looks like it does). The `INTERFACE` visibility is mostly used in header-only (interface) libraries, and I rarely see it useful.

Comment: P1_configuration was created using add_library(P1_configuration INTERFACE), as it doesn't contain any headers/sources only compile options